# Arbitrary Paper Size in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, paper-size

I would like to typeset a document into a single-page PDF that may be a meter long.  Clearly this is not a A4, A5, A6 page size.

Is it possible to specify arbitrary page sizes, like with the geometry class in LaTeX?

Comment: See http://wiki.contextgarden.net/PaperSetup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, e.g. `\definepapersize[looong][width=150mm, height=1001mm]`.

You can then use `\setuppapersize[looong][looong]` to typeset looong pages on looong sheets of paper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer to my RTFM question.  Sorry, I am new to ConTeXt and still overwhelmed by all the possibilities.